# How can i set properties of component in angular

Tags: angular

I am playing around with some custom component in Angular and are wondering if there is a way to achieve the following. I have a form which i want to dynamically
show or hide different form elements in an reactive form. On normal inputs that is not an issue but i have several instances of a custom control which i set in template like this.

```
<app-dropdown placeholder="Test"
[disabled]="showEditNewButton"
guid='820E04E0-8084-4D9C-A268-D8C0D21E74F6'
formControlName="test">
</app-dropdown>
```

So the question now is how can i via code in the component of the parent can set the placeholder string or the guid ? Also what is the best way to hide or remove certain custom controls from Dom based on a value in another field on the reactive form. Keep in mind there might be multiple instances of this same component just with different formControlName and guid.

I have in my component already specified @Input() so i can send data from template to component.

```
  @Input() guid: string;
  @Input() options: IServerDropdownOption[];
  @Input() placeholder = '--Select--';
  @Input() isRequired = false;

  private _disabled = false;
  @Input() set disabled(isDisabled: boolean) {
      this._disabled = isDisabled;
  };
  get disabled() {
      return this._disabled;
  }

  options$: Observable<Array<ServerDropdownOption>>;
  value;
  selectField;
  form: FormGroup;
  onChange;
  onTouched;
  validateFn: Function;
```

The question is how can i send data to the child component from the parent component like i want to via code to set the placeholder.

Comment: to remove the input from Dom use *ngIf ,e.g.`<input *ngIf="myForm.get('nameOfAnotherControl').value!='a'>`, for give properties from parent simple use `@Input`, see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs

Comment: I have already @Input() but i am unclear how i would access the element from the parent component.

Comment: You can use ViewChild and ViewChildren, but in general the idea is has "variables" in the parent, you can use an Array of variables or an Array of object, sorry I'm  being a bit thick today

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngModel and use JSON object to input a combinatin